# Looking for a circuit with 5 switches and lamps where one switch disables the others

Tags: switches

Can this circuit be extended to 5 lamps and switches?

[image: schematic]

<sub>Image source:

[Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - "[Wiring two lamps so that the one disables the other](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/642308)" answer by user [*Transistor*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/73158/transistor)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Yes, any circuit can be extended with enough work and additional components. Sometimes you need to leave the old circuit behind. Was that really your question, or have you maybe already thought of an approach? Or are you maybe not actually interested in extending this highly esoteric circuit to five lamps, but are actually looking for a solution to a concrete problem?

Comment: I am wanting a circuit with 5 switches and 5 lamps designed so that when one switch is pressed one lamp comes on and the others are disabled. This one works perfect for a 2 lamp system but when I tried expanding it to 5 it didn’t work the same. Just wondering if I did something wrong. I connected the others in series (lamp 2 to sw3 instead of back to sw1 etc. then lamp 5 back to sw1). Am I wrong in thinking this is how to extend the circuit?

Comment: Hey, this is the first time you tell us how you went about extending the circuit! We might be able to help with the! Please **edit** your question to explain what you did, of possible with a schematic, as well!

Comment: Sorry, I’m a beginner. I don’t have a schematic of how I extended it but I basically went from neutral/neg side of lamp 2 to sw3 instead of back to sw1 and so forth down the line. Then I went from neutral/neg side of lamp5 back to sw1. I’m probably not very clear and I’m sorry if I can’t explain it well enough.

Comment: I can't imagine that in my head very well. Take your existing schematic and draw in these connections you made.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "radio button circuit" because it behaves the same as the pushbuttons on an old car radio - press any button, and any previously-selected button is cancelled.  There are many examples on the innergoogle, covering different switch configurations, types of lamps, power sources, etc.

Comment: @Huffga please update your question ...do not write a clarification in a comment ... this site is not a forum where you get to slowly dribble information ... people should not have to read your comment to learn what you are trying to do

Comment: Constantine A. B. I just edited my post with my schematic of how I extended the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

this circuit works on the basis the SCRs for each lamp steal the power that would turn on the SCR for the other lamp.

generalising it to any number of lamsp can be done  by a slight rearangement and adding some diodes,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbsEz8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

repeat the part in the box 5 times   connect all the `R` toghether,
all the `D` together all the `A` together all the `D`  together and al the `G` together.

`D1` and `D2`  substrited with a LED for a  "ready" indicator
`SW1` can be changed to a toggle type to allow a power off mode to save the battery. (or add a toggle switch in series with `SW1`)

Answer (score 2):

When one lamp is on the others are disabled.

[image]